# Merge data to print after execution in OpenMP with C

Tags: c, openmp

I'm using OpenMP to run a function in multiple threads. This function returns a `MyStruct` variable, which can be seen below:

```
typedef struct 
{
     int elements[8];
     uint64_t score;

} MyStruct;
```

After running the function in a `#pragma omp parallel` section, I get `p` `MyStruct` variables, where `p` is the number of threads (note that these are private variables to each thread).

At this point, I can print all these `MyStruct` variables and visually look for the one with the greatest `score`, but I don't find this elegant enough.

How can I select from all those `MyStruct` variables the one with the greatest score and only print that one?

Comment: "After running the function in a #pragma omp parallel section, I get p MyStruct variables" and "print all these MyStruct variables" --> post that code.

Comment: The simplest is to write at the end of every thread each of these local vars to a global array indexed by thread id. Then on main thread, find the greatest and print it. You can also compute the greatest directly in the threads, but it requires atomic operations and it will take a longer time (vs sequential version) and is more complex to program.

Comment: Alain Merigot, that is what I've finally done. Would you mind to post an answer saying just the same as in your comment so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to print the variable score in your struct that is the biggest.

You could create a while loop that while score exists, and move through each one.
While you move through each one you create a tmp.
If score > tmp.
tmp = score;
Then at the end your tmp will hold the max value.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! This is similar to what I've finally done, but the key idea in this was from Alain Merigot. Nevertheless, thanks Alan Barret II

Answer (score 0):

You could define a user-defined reduction to accomplish this task as part of the join operation of your parallel region:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction \
    (mymax:MyStruct:(omp_in.score > omp_out.score) ? omp_in : omp_out) \
    initializer(omp_priv = {.score = INT_MIN})

void example() {
    MyStruct s;

#pragma omp parallel reduction(mymax:s)
    {
        fill_struct_with_value(&s);
    }
}
```

I wrote this from the top of my head, so it may or may not compile, but the general idea of this is there.

Note, the above code requires a compiler that supports OpenMP version 4.0 or greater.